# PhpStorm IntelliSense for class_alias

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm gives me full IntelliSense when I have use statement of top. For example:

```
use Framework\MVC\Route;

Route::setRoutes($routes);
```

But, I am using `class_alias` as [Does not even work on same file]:

```
class_alias("Framework\\MVC\\Route", "Route");
```

Now, when I write `Route::` I get no IntelliSense. In fact, it even shows some warning saying unknown class `Route`. How can I get through this issue?

Comment: 1) Q -- why do you need to use class alias in first place? What's wrong (or why can't you use) `use` statement directly? 2) The only option that I'm aware of is to declare such aliased classes manually in some separate `.php` file (that will be used by IDE only). E.g. `<?php class Route extends \Framework\MVC\Route {}` -- this tells that `Route` is child of `\Framework\MVC\Route` hence it inherits all the methods of the parent class.

Comment: @LazyOne I use `class_alias` because it is a short-hand feature. For example I have a `Framework\\Helpers\\Storage\\Session` class, which I prefer to use as `Session` throughout the project and it works. I want my IDE to work accordingly.

Comment: My question was -- why can't you use `use Framework\MVC\Route;` statement? -- it gives the same result in the scope of current file -- you will refer to that class as `Route` anyway. 2) `class_alias` is not supported by PhpStorm ATM -- watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11936 ticket to get updates on progress.

Comment: @LazyOne because I am lazy to type and I want to use alias.

Comment: Quite odd reason .. considering the fact that IDE inserts such entry for you when you use such class for the first time... In any case: I gave you the possible workaround and link to the original ticket.